# 4-pin Hirose connector to BNC

Tags: cables

Is there any way to convert n 4-pin Hirose connector to BNC ??

With this [camera](http://www.theimagingsource.com/en_US/products/cameras/usb-ccd-mono/dmk42buc03/) the the trigger is 4 pin hirose connector. But the trigger from my data generator [DG2020A](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS472US472&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS472US472&sclient=psy-ab&q=Dg2020a&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=1&ion=1&biw=1920&bih=955&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&cad=b) is 2state (0-5V) and a ( BNC output ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, make a custom cable with a 4-pin Hirose at one end and a BNC at the other end.

Similar to this:

[image]

[This document](http://s1.archive.theimagingsource.com/publications/whitepapers-cameras/wp224272trigo/c087ecc49679e8b2ab124b70fd9d616490a7dc6c3a14bd21f7515e6b7bcd0be8/wp224272trigo.en_US.pdf) specifies the Hirose pinout:

[image]

This should tell you how to wire it.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1R1zvru.png Could you please tell me which pin among these 4 should go to the BNC positive and negative.

Comment: @abhilash I've updated the answer with the Hirose pinout information.